# I can’t create the tables in the database (PostgreSQL), Java Spring boot?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am working on a mini-project in Java Spring Boot. I have created 4 classes (**user, admin, driver, and parking**), and I used the PostgreSQL database. I don't know why I can't create tables in the database. Here is the content of the application.properties file:

---

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/immsDB
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=sc_IMMS
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=123
```

---

concerning the class codes are as follows
**User Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data

@NoArgsConstructor

public class Utilisateur {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_user;
    @Column(name = "login",nullable = false, unique = true,length = 100)
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "password",nullable = false,length = 100)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "role",nullable = false, length = 100)
    private Role role;
    @Column(name = "nom_user",nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String nom_user;
    @Column(name = "prenom_user",nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String prenom_user;

    public Utilisateur(String login, String password, Role role, String nom_user, String prenom_user) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.nom_user = nom_user;
        this.prenom_user = prenom_user;
    }
}
```

---

*Admin Class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "admins")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Admin extends Utilisateur {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_admin;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_park")
    ArrayList<Parking> parkingList;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_chauffeur")
    ArrayList<Chauffeur> chauffeurList;
    
    public Admin(Long id_admin, String login, String password, Role role, 
            String nom_user, String prenom_user){
        super(login,password, role, nom_user,prenom_user);
        this.id_admin = id_admin;
    }
}
```

---

**Driver Class
**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chauffeurs")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Chauffeur extends Utilisateur {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_chauffeur;

    @ManyToOne
    Admin admin ;

    public Chauffeur(Long id_chauff, String login, String password, Role role, 
            String nom_user, String prenom_user){
        super(login,password, role, nom_user,prenom_user);
        this.id_chauffeur = id_chauff;
    }
}
```

---

**Parking Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parkings")
@Data

public class Parking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_park;
    @Column(name = "nom_park", nullable = true)
    private String nom_park;
    @Column(name = "x_park", nullable = true)
    private double x_park;
    @Column(name = "y_park", nullable = true)
    private double y_park;

    @ManyToOne
    Admin admin;
}
```

the main's class codes is :

```
@ComponentScan({"com.cheng.imms.parking.service","com.cheng.imms.parking.repository"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.cheng.imms.parking.model")
@EntityScan("com.cheng.imms.parking.repository")
@SpringBootApplication

public class ImmsApplication {
    @GetMapping("/hi")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHello(){
        //System.out.println(adminServ.findChauffeurList());
        return "Hello i'm admin's page";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ImmsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

After I made some changes to the main class, adding @EntityScan and @ComponentScan, I encountered another problem which is:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'chauffeurRep': No qualifying bean of type 'com.cheng.imms.parking.repository.ChauffeurRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

thanks for your helps.

Comment: and what error do you get when you save an object ?

Comment: i haven't any error, that the reason that leads me to post my pub.                                        @ComponentScan({"com.cheng.imms.parking.service"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.cheng.imms.parking.model")
@EntityScan("com.cheng.imms.parking.repository")
@SpringBootApplication
public class ImmsApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ImmsApplication.class, args);
 }
}                                                                                                                                   you find above the main function code